# Error: Assertation failed allegro5\addons\font\text.c line 77 expression font

Tags: c++, allegro5

Does anyone have any idea how I could solve this error, I have the correct ttf file so I don't see why Im getting this error when I debug Here is all my code below I don't really know where to start with this problem

```
#include <iostream>
#include <allegro5/allegro.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_native_dialog.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_font.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_ttf.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_primitives.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_image.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_audio.h>
#include <allegro5/allegro_acodec.h>

#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\globals.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\buttons.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\screenState.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\nebulaBig.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\tutorialShoot.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\player.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\bullets.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\bulletEnemy.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\cometBig.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\cometSmall.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\healthup.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\enemyShipNormal.h"
#include "Galaxy Quest Source\\backgroundAnim.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    /*SHELL VARIABLES*/
    unsigned short addonCheck = 0;
    unsigned long animCounter = 0;

    bool running = false;
    bool rendering = false;

    int gameFPS = 0;
    int frames = 0;
    float gameTime = 0;
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    int framesElapsed = 0;

    NebulaBig nebulaBigC;
    TutorialShoot tutorialShootC;

    Buttons *bPlay = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bHelp = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bOptn = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bBack = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bExit = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bMenu = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bExit2 = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bVolumeP = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bVolumeM = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bDifficultyP = new Buttons();
    Buttons *bDifficultyM = new Buttons();

    Bullet bullets[20];
    //BulletEnemy bulletEnemy[20];

    CometBig cometsBig[20];
    CometSmall cometsSmall[20];
    HealthUp healthUp[1];

    EnemyShip enemyShip[1];

    Player ship;

    GameBackground bgStars;
    GameBackground bgNebulas;

    /*INITIALIZE ALLEGRO 5*/
    al_init();
    if (!al_init()) {
        al_show_native_message_box(0, "ERROR", "Failed to initialize Allegro 5!", "Press OK to terminate.", 0, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    /*ALLEGRO VARIABLES*/
    ALLEGRO_DISPLAY *display = 0;
    ALLEGRO_EVENT_QUEUE *eventQueue = 0;
    ALLEGRO_TIMER *timer = 0;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *mouseBMP;
    ALLEGRO_FONT *mainFont, *smallFont, *titleFont, *bigFont;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *player, *playerDamaged, *playerLeft, *playerRight, *playerShield, *enemyNormal;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *cometBigBMP, *cometSmallBMP, *livesIconRotated;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *bulletPlayer, *bulletEnemyBMP;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *nebulaBig, *nebulaSmall, *nebulaVerySmall;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *gameScreenFast, *gameScreenNebulas, *livesIcon;
    ALLEGRO_BITMAP *tutorialShoot;
    ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *introSound;
    ALLEGRO_SAMPLE *bulletSound, *explosionSound, *healthdownSound, *healthupSound;

    /*CREATE DISPLAY*/
    al_set_new_display_flags(ALLEGRO_FULLSCREEN);
    display = al_create_display(screenW, screenH);
    if (!display) {
        al_show_native_message_box(0, "ERROR", "Failed to initialize the display!", "Press OK to terminate.", 0, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    al_hide_mouse_cursor(display);

    /*INSTALL ADDONS*/
    al_init_font_addon(); addonCheck++;
    al_init_ttf_addon(); addonCheck++;
    al_init_primitives_addon(); addonCheck++;
    al_init_image_addon(); addonCheck++;
    al_install_keyboard(); addonCheck++;
    al_install_mouse(); addonCheck++;
    al_install_audio(); addonCheck++;
    al_init_acodec_addon(); addonCheck++;
    if (addonCheck != 8) {
        al_show_native_message_box(0, "ERROR", "Failed to load Allegro addons!", "Press OK to terminate.", 0, ALLEGRO_MESSAGEBOX_ERROR);
        return -1;
    }

    /*FILE LOADING*/

    //LOADING SCREEN
    bigFont = al_load_font("HOOG0555.ttf", 55, 0);
    al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
    al_draw_text(bigFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2.5, screenH / 2, 0, "LOADING.");
    al_flip_display();

    //LOADING IMAGES
    titleFont = al_load_font("HOOG0555.ttf", 125, 0);
    mainFont = al_load_font("HOOG0555.ttf", 35, 0);
    smallFont = al_load_font("HOOG0555.ttf", 15, 0);

    ALLEGRO_PATH *imagesP = al_get_standard_path(ALLEGRO_RESOURCES_PATH);
    al_append_path_component(imagesP, "images");
    al_change_directory(al_path_cstr(imagesP, '/'));
    al_destroy_path(imagesP);

    mouseBMP = al_load_bitmap("mouse.png");

    player = al_load_bitmap("player.png");
    playerDamaged = al_load_bitmap("playerDamaged.png");
    playerLeft = al_load_bitmap("playerLeft.png");
    playerRight = al_load_bitmap("playerRight.png");
    playerShield = al_load_bitmap("shield.png");

    enemyNormal = al_load_bitmap("enemyShip.png");

    cometBigBMP = al_load_bitmap("meteorBig.png");
    cometSmallBMP = al_load_bitmap("meteorSmall.png");

    bulletPlayer = al_load_bitmap("laserGreen.png");
    bulletEnemyBMP = al_load_bitmap("laserRed.png");

    nebulaBig = al_load_bitmap("nebulaBig.png");
    nebulaSmall = al_load_bitmap("nebulaSmall.png");
    nebulaVerySmall = al_load_bitmap("nebulaVerySmall.png");

    gameScreenFast = al_load_bitmap("movingBGlines.png");
    al_convert_mask_to_alpha(gameScreenFast, al_map_rgb(35, 10, 55));
    gameScreenNebulas = al_load_bitmap("movingBGnebulas.png");
    al_convert_mask_to_alpha(gameScreenNebulas, al_map_rgb(35, 10, 55));
    livesIcon = al_load_bitmap("life.png");
    livesIconRotated = al_load_bitmap("life180.png");

    tutorialShoot = al_load_bitmap("tutorialShoot.png");

    al_draw_text(bigFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2.5, screenH / 2, 0, "LOADING..");
    al_flip_display();

    //LOADING SOUNDS
    al_reserve_samples(5);

    ALLEGRO_PATH *soundsP = al_get_standard_path(ALLEGRO_RESOURCES_PATH);
    al_append_path_component(soundsP, "sounds");
    al_change_directory(al_path_cstr(soundsP, '/'));
    al_destroy_path(soundsP);

    introSound = al_load_sample("introSound.wav");

    bulletSound = al_load_sample("bulletSound.wav");
    explosionSound = al_load_sample("explosionSound.wav");
    healthdownSound = al_load_sample("healthdownSound.wav");
    healthupSound = al_load_sample("healthupSound.wav");

    al_draw_text(bigFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2.5, screenH / 2, 0, "LOADING...");
    al_flip_display();

start:
    bPlay->setHover(false);
    objectCount = 0;
    shieldTimer = 5;
    enemyFireTimer = 0;

    /*FADE-IN COUNTERS*/
    counter255r = 35;
    counter255g = 10;
    counter255b = 55;
    counter185r = 35;
    counter185g = 10;
    counter185b = 55;
    counterHelp185r = 35;
    counterHelp185g = 10;
    counterHelp185b = 55;
    counterHelp255r = 35;
    counterHelp255g = 10;
    counterHelp255b = 55;

    /*GAME OBJECT INITIALIZATION*/
    nebulaBigC.init(nebulaBig);
    tutorialShootC.init(tutorialShoot);

    bPlay->init(screenW / 2, screenH / 2 + 100, 65, 18, bigFont);
    bHelp->init(screenW / 2, screenH / 2 + 140, 65, 18, bigFont);
    bOptn->init(screenW / 2, screenH / 2 + 180, 65, 18, bigFont);
    bBack->init(screenW / 2, screenH - 80, 65, 18, bigFont);
    bExit->init(screenW / 2, screenH / 2 + 220, 65, 18, bigFont);
    bMenu->init(screenW / 2, screenH / 2 + 40, 65, 18, bigFont);
    bExit2->init(screenW / 2, screenH / 2 + 80, 65, 18, bigFont);
    bVolumeP->init(screenW / 2 + 90, screenH / 3, 18, 18, bigFont);
    bVolumeM->init(screenW / 2 - 90, screenH / 3, 18, 18, bigFont);
    bDifficultyP->init(screenW / 2 + 100, screenH / 3 + 175, 18, 18, bigFont);
    bDifficultyM->init(screenW / 2 - 100, screenH / 3 + 175, 18, 18, bigFont);

    initBullet(bullets, bulletPlayer, bulletSound, explosionSound);
    bulletEnemy->init(bulletEnemy, bulletEnemyBMP, bulletSound, explosionSound, healthdownSound);

    initCometBig(cometsBig, cometBigBMP, healthdownSound);
    initCometSmall(cometsSmall, cometSmallBMP, healthdownSound);
    healthUp->init(healthUp, livesIconRotated, healthupSound);

    enemyShip->init(enemyShip, enemyNormal, explosionSound);

    ship.init(player, playerLeft, playerRight, playerDamaged, playerShield, livesIcon);

    bgStars.init(gameScreenFast, 6, 1);
    bgNebulas.init(gameScreenNebulas, 2, 2);

    /*EQ, TIMER AND REGISTER SOURCES*/
    eventQueue = al_create_event_queue();
    timer = al_create_timer(1.0 / 120);

    al_register_event_source(eventQueue, al_get_timer_event_source(timer));
    al_register_event_source(eventQueue, al_get_display_event_source(display));
    al_register_event_source(eventQueue, al_get_mouse_event_source());
    al_register_event_source(eventQueue, al_get_keyboard_event_source());

    /*FINAL PREPERATIONS, START TIMER*/
    running = true;
    ScreenStateC *screenStateC = new ScreenStateC();
    screenStateC->setToState(1);

    srand(time(NULL));

    al_start_timer(timer);
    gameTime = al_current_time();
    al_play_sample(introSound, volume, ALLEGRO_AUDIO_PAN_NONE, 1.0, ALLEGRO_PLAYMODE_ONCE, 0);

    while (running) {
        if (screenState[TITLESCREEN] && !screenState[GAMESCREEN]) {
            ALLEGRO_EVENT titleEvent;
            al_wait_for_event(eventQueue, &titleEvent);

            if (titleEvent.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES) {
                mouseX = titleEvent.mouse.x;
                mouseY = titleEvent.mouse.y;
            }

            if (titleEvent.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_UP) {
                if (!screenState[HELPSCREEN] && !screenState[OPTIONSCREEN] && !screenState[GAMESCREEN]) {
                    if (bPlay->getHover()) {
                        if (titleEvent.mouse.button & 1) {
                            screenStateC->setToState(2);
                        }
                    }
                    if (bHelp->getHover()) {
                        if (titleEvent.mouse.button & 1) {
                            screenStateC->setToState(3);
                        }
                    }
                    if (bOptn->getHover()) {
                        if (titleEvent.mouse.button & 1) {
                            screenStateC->setToState(4);
                        }
                    }
                    if (bExit->getHover()) {
                        if (titleEvent.mouse.button & 1) {
                            screenState[TITLESCREEN] = false;
                            running = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (screenState[HELPSCREEN]) {
                    if (bBack->getHover() & 1) {
                        screenStateC->setToState(1);
                    }
                }
                else if (screenState[OPTIONSCREEN]) {
                    if (bBack->getHover() & 1) {
                        screenStateC->setToState(1);
                    }
                    if (bVolumeP->getHover() & 1) {
                        if (volume == 0.0) {
                            volume = 0.2;
                        }
                        else if (volume == 0.2) {
                            volume = 0.4;
                        }
                        else if (volume == 0.4) {
                            volume = 0.6;
                        }
                        else if (volume == 0.6) {
                            volume = 0.8;
                        }
                        else if (volume == 0.8) {
                            volume = 1.0;
                        }
                    }
                    if (bVolumeM->getHover() & 1) {
                        if (volume == 0.2) {
                            volume = 0.0;
                        }
                        else if (volume == 0.4) {
                            volume = 0.2;
                        }
                        else if (volume == 0.6) {
                            volume = 0.4;
                        }
                        else if (volume == 0.8) {
                            volume = 0.6;
                        }
                        else if (volume == 1.0) {
                            volume = 0.8;
                        }
                    }
                    if (bDifficultyP->getHover() & 1) {
                        if (difficulty[EASY]) {
                            difficulty[EASY] = false;
                            difficulty[NORM] = true;
                            difficulty[HARD] = false;
                        }
                        else if (difficulty[NORM]) {
                            difficulty[EASY] = false;
                            difficulty[NORM] = false;
                            difficulty[HARD] = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (bDifficultyM->getHover() & 1) {
                        if (difficulty[NORM]) {
                            difficulty[EASY] = true;
                            difficulty[NORM] = false;
                            difficulty[HARD] = false;
                        }
                        else if (difficulty[HARD]) {
                            difficulty[EASY] = false;
                            difficulty[NORM] = true;
                            difficulty[HARD] = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            if (titleEvent.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_DISPLAY_CLOSE) {
                running = false;
            }

            if (titleEvent.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP) {
                switch (titleEvent.keyboard.keycode) {
                case ALLEGRO_KEY_F3:
                    if (keys[F3])
                        keys[F3] = false;
                    else if (!keys[F3])
                        keys[F3] = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (titleEvent.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER) {
                rendering = true;

                if (screenState[HELPSCREEN]) {
                    tutorialShootC.update();

                    if (tutorialShootC.getFinal()) {
                        if (counterHelp185r < 185)
                            counterHelp185r++;
                        if (counterHelp185g < 185)
                            counterHelp185g++;
                        if (counterHelp185b < 185)
                            counterHelp185b++;

                        if (counterHelp255r < 255)
                            counterHelp255r++;
                        if (counterHelp255g < 255)
                            counterHelp255g++;
                        if (counterHelp255b < 255)
                            counterHelp255b++;
                    }
                }

                if (nebulaBigC.getFinal()) {
                    if (counter185r < 185)
                        counter185r++;
                    if (counter185g < 185)
                        counter185g++;
                    if (counter185b < 185)
                        counter185b++;

                    if (counter255r < 255)
                        counter255r++;
                    if (counter255g < 255)
                        counter255g++;
                    if (counter255b < 255)
                        counter255b++;

                    if (counter255g == 254);
                    bPlay->hoverDetect();
                    bHelp->hoverDetect();
                    bOptn->hoverDetect();
                    bBack->hoverDetect();
                    bExit->hoverDetect();
                    bVolumeP->hoverDetect();
                    bVolumeM->hoverDetect();
                    bDifficultyP->hoverDetect();
                    bDifficultyM->hoverDetect();
                }

                nebulaBigC.update();

                framesElapsed++;
                seconds = framesElapsed / 120;

                if (seconds >= 60) {
                    minutes++;
                    seconds = 0;
                    framesElapsed = 0;
                }

                frames++;
                if (al_current_time() - gameTime >= 1) {
                    gameTime = al_current_time();
                    gameFPS = frames;
                    frames = 0;
                }
            }

            if (rendering && al_is_event_queue_empty(eventQueue)) {
                rendering = false;

                al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(35, 10, 55));

                if (!screenState[HELPSCREEN] && !screenState[OPTIONSCREEN]) {
                    nebulaBigC.render();

                    al_draw_text(titleFont, al_map_rgb(counter255r, counter255g, counter255b), screenW / 2 - 30, screenH / 7 + 20, 1, "GALAXY");
                    al_draw_text(titleFont, al_map_rgb(counter255r, counter255g, counter255b), screenW / 2, screenH / 4 + 50, 1, "QUEST");
                    al_draw_text(smallFont, al_map_rgb(counter255r, counter255g, counter255b), screenW / 2, screenH / 1.05, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, author);
                    al_draw_text(smallFont, al_map_rgb(counter255r, counter255g, counter255b), screenW / 1.56, screenH / 3 + 54, 1, version);

                    /*DEBUG MODE*/
                    if (keys[F3]) {
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "FPS: %i", gameFPS);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 17, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Time: %i min, %i sec", minutes, seconds);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 29, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Frames: %i", framesElapsed);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 41, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Mouse X: %i", mouseX);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 53, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Mouse Y: %i", mouseY);
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bPlay->getX() - bPlay->getBoundX(), bPlay->getY(), bPlay->getX() + bPlay->getBoundX(), bPlay->getY() + bPlay->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bHelp->getX() - bHelp->getBoundX(), bHelp->getY(), bHelp->getX() + bHelp->getBoundX(), bHelp->getY() + bHelp->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bOptn->getX() - bOptn->getBoundX(), bOptn->getY(), bOptn->getX() + bOptn->getBoundX(), bOptn->getY() + bOptn->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bExit->getX() - bExit->getBoundX(), bExit->getY(), bExit->getX() + bExit->getBoundX(), bExit->getY() + bExit->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                    }

                    bPlay->render(1);
                    bHelp->render(2);
                    bOptn->render(3);
                    bExit->render(5);
                }
                else if (screenState[HELPSCREEN] && !screenState[OPTIONSCREEN]) {
                    tutorialShootC.render();

                    al_draw_text(bigFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp255r, counterHelp255g, counterHelp255b), screenW / 5, 40, 0, "BASICS");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp185r, counterHelp185g, counterHelp185b), screenW / 30, screenH / 6, 0, "Galaxy quest is a space invaders type game,");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp185r, counterHelp185g, counterHelp185b), screenW / 30, screenH / 6 + 35, 0, "in which the                is to get the highest");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp255r, counterHelp255g, counterHelp255b), screenW / 30, screenH / 6 + 35, 0, "                  objective");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp185r, counterHelp185g, counterHelp185b), screenW / 30, screenH / 6 + 70, 0, "possible score.           are earned by destroying");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp255r, counterHelp255g, counterHelp255b), screenW / 30 + 5, screenH / 6 + 70, 0, "                       Points");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp185r, counterHelp185g, counterHelp185b), screenW / 30, screenH / 6 + 105, 0, "comets and enemy space ships.");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp185r, counterHelp185g, counterHelp185b), screenW / 30, screenH / 6 + 140, 0, "Enemy commoness scales with difficulty setting.");

                    al_draw_text(bigFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp255r, counterHelp255g, counterHelp255b), screenW / 5, screenH / 2 - 25, 0, "POWER UPS");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp185r, counterHelp185g, counterHelp185b), screenW / 30, screenH / 2 + 70, 0, "During the game you might pick up health power");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp185r, counterHelp185g, counterHelp185b), screenW / 30, screenH / 2 + 105, 0, "ups which will replenish your lives. The higher");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterHelp185r, counterHelp185g, counterHelp185b), screenW / 30, screenH / 2 + 140, 0, "the difficulty, the rarer the power ups!");

                    /*DEBUG MODE*/
                    if (keys[F3]) {
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "FPS: %i", gameFPS);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 17, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Time: %i min, %i sec", minutes, seconds);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 29, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Frames: %i", framesElapsed);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 41, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Mouse X: %i", mouseX);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 53, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Mouse Y: %i", mouseY);
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bBack->getX() - bBack->getBoundX(), bBack->getY(), bBack->getX() + bBack->getBoundX(), bBack->getY() + bBack->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                    }

                    bBack->render(4);
                }
                else if (!screenState[HELPSCREEN] && screenState[OPTIONSCREEN]) {
                    /*DEBUG MODE*/
                    if (keys[F3]) {
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "FPS: %i", gameFPS);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 17, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Time: %i min, %i sec", minutes, seconds);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 29, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Frames: %i", framesElapsed);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 41, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Mouse X: %i", mouseX);
                        al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 53, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Mouse Y: %i", mouseY);
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bBack->getX() - bBack->getBoundX(), bBack->getY(), bBack->getX() + bBack->getBoundX(), bBack->getY() + bBack->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bVolumeP->getX() - bVolumeP->getBoundX(), bVolumeP->getY(), bVolumeP->getX() + bVolumeP->getBoundX(), bVolumeP->getY() + bVolumeP->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bVolumeM->getX() - bVolumeM->getBoundX(), bVolumeM->getY(), bVolumeM->getX() + bVolumeM->getBoundX(), bVolumeM->getY() + bVolumeM->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bDifficultyP->getX() - bDifficultyP->getBoundX(), bDifficultyP->getY(), bDifficultyP->getX() + bDifficultyP->getBoundX(), bDifficultyP->getY() + bDifficultyP->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bDifficultyM->getX() - bDifficultyM->getBoundX(), bDifficultyM->getY(), bDifficultyM->getX() + bDifficultyM->getBoundX(), bDifficultyM->getY() + bDifficultyM->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                    }

                    al_draw_text(bigFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 - 60, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "Volume");
                    if (volume == 0.0)
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "0%");
                    else if (volume == 0.2)
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "20%");
                    else if (volume == 0.4)
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "40%");
                    else if (volume == 0.6)
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "60%");
                    else if (volume == 0.8)
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "80%");
                    else if (volume == 1.0)
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 5, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "100%");

                    al_draw_text(bigFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, (screenH / 3 + 175) - 60, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "Difficulty");
                    if (difficulty[EASY])
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 180, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "EASY");
                    else if (difficulty[NORM])
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 180, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "NORM");
                    else if (difficulty[HARD])
                        al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 3 + 180, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_CENTRE, "HARD");

                    bBack->render(4);
                    bVolumeP->render(7);
                    bVolumeM->render(8);
                    bDifficultyP->render(9);
                    bDifficultyM->render(10);
                }

                al_draw_bitmap(mouseBMP, mouseX, mouseY, 0);

                al_flip_display();
                al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
            }
        }

        /**********************************************************
        G A M E         L O O P
        **********************************************************/

        if (screenState[GAMESCREEN] && !screenState[TITLESCREEN]) {

            ALLEGRO_EVENT gameEvent;
            al_wait_for_event(eventQueue, &gameEvent);

            if (gameEvent.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_AXES) {
                mouseX = gameEvent.mouse.x;
                mouseY = gameEvent.mouse.y;
            }

            if (gameEvent.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_MOUSE_BUTTON_UP) {
                if (screenState[MENUSCREEN]) {
                    if (bExit2->getHover()) {
                        if (gameEvent.mouse.button & 1) {
                            screenState[GAMESCREEN] = false;
                            running = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (bMenu->getHover()) {
                        if (gameEvent.mouse.button & 1) {
                            screenStateC->setToState(1);
                            goto start;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }


                if (counterGame185r > 36) {
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterGame185r, counterGame185g, counterGame185b), screenW / 2, screenH / 6, 1, "Use WSAD to move");
                    al_draw_text(mainFont, al_map_rgb(counterGame185r, counterGame185g, counterGame185b), screenW / 2, screenH / 5 + 30, 1, "Use SPACE to shoot");
                }

                if (ship.getLives() <= 0) {
                    al_draw_text(titleFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 2 - 80, 1, "GAME OVER");
                }

                al_draw_filled_rectangle(5, 41, shieldTimer / 10, 59, al_map_rgb(255, 204, 0));
                al_draw_rectangle(5, 41, 1200 / 10, 59, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 2);
                al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), 5, 65, 0, "Score: %i", ship.getScore());

                /*DEBUG MODE*/
                if (keys[F3]) {
                    al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 77, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "FPS: %i", gameFPS);
                    al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 89, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Time: %i min, %i sec", minutes, seconds);
                    al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 101, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Frames: %i", framesElapsed);
                    al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 113, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Mouse X: %i", mouseX);
                    al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 125, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Mouse Y: %i", mouseY);
                    al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 137, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Objects: %i", objectCount);
                    al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 149, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Lives: %i", ship.getLives());
                    al_draw_textf(smallFont, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 0), 5, 161, ALLEGRO_ALIGN_LEFT, "Shield: %i", ship.getShield());

                    al_draw_bitmap(mouseBMP, mouseX, mouseY, 0);
                }

                if (screenState[MENUSCREEN]) {
                    /*DEBUG MODE*/
                    if (keys[F3]) {
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bExit2->getX() - bExit2->getBoundX(), bExit2->getY(), bExit2->getX() + bExit2->getBoundX(), bExit2->getY() + bExit2->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                        al_draw_filled_rectangle(bMenu->getX() - bMenu->getBoundX(), bMenu->getY(), bMenu->getX() + bMenu->getBoundX(), bMenu->getY() + bMenu->getBoundY() * 2, al_map_rgb(0, 255, 20));
                    }

                    if (ship.getLives() > 0)
                        al_draw_text(titleFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 2 - 80, 1, "PAUSED");
                    else if (ship.getLives() <= 0)
                        al_draw_text(titleFont, al_map_rgb(255, 255, 255), screenW / 2, screenH / 2 - 80, 1, "GAME OVER");

                    bExit2->render(5);
                    bMenu->render(6);

                    al_draw_bitmap(mouseBMP, mouseX, mouseY, 0);
                }

                al_flip_display();
                al_clear_to_color(al_map_rgb(0, 0, 0));
            }
        }
    }

    delete screenStateC;
    delete bPlay;
    delete bHelp;
    delete bOptn;
    delete bBack;
    delete bExit;
    delete bMenu;
    delete bExit2;
    delete bVolumeP;
    delete bVolumeM;
    delete bDifficultyP;
    delete bDifficultyM;

    al_destroy_display(display);
    al_destroy_event_queue(eventQueue);
    al_destroy_timer(timer);
    al_destroy_bitmap(mouseBMP);
    al_destroy_font(mainFont);
    al_destroy_font(smallFont);
    al_destroy_font(titleFont);
    al_destroy_font(bigFont);

    al_destroy_bitmap(player);
    al_destroy_bitmap(playerDamaged);
    al_destroy_bitmap(playerLeft);
    al_destroy_bitmap(playerRight);
    al_destroy_bitmap(playerShield);
    al_destroy_bitmap(bulletPlayer);
    al_destroy_bitmap(nebulaBig);
    al_destroy_bitmap(nebulaSmall);
    al_destroy_bitmap(nebulaVerySmall);
    al_destroy_bitmap(livesIcon);

    al_destroy_sample(bulletSound);
    al_destroy_sample(introSound);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. You will have to provide some code so we can help you

Comment: @Drakes Hi thanks, I just updated my post with the majority of my code I removed some of the things I really don't feel is causing the error

Comment: What is on line 77 of text.c?

Comment: @Drakes That's what I can't find

Comment: Check that the font is correctly loaded, probably the pointer is still NULL or an invalid memory address. Never assume a resource will load with no errors

Answer (score 0):

Your example is too massive to decipher, but I will give you some tips.

1) Always initialize your variables.

2) Don't load resources before al_init runs. This means all those objects you have before al_init would automatically fail to load any resources they need. Same goes for global objects because they are created before al_init runs.

3) If a resource is not loading, then one of the following probably applies :

A) The file name is incorrect.

B) The current working directory is wrong.

C) The resource format you're trying to load is not supported.

You can eliminate 3A by trying an absolute path for your resoures. If the call then succeeds, you know your problem is B), because the program is looking in the wrong directory for your files. If you've ruled out A and you fixed B by setting the correct working directory for your program, and the loading function returns `NULL` then C is most likely the answer.

If C) is the problem, then there are a couple options to fix it.

1) Make sure support for the format you're using has been built into the version of allegro you are using.

2) Submit a patch to allegro to support the unsupported format.